# Phonegap Cordova IOS : Detect external keyboard

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, keyboard

Using phonegap on IOS : is there a way of detecting when an external keyboard is in use ?

Already using ionic keyboard plugin, ignores external keyboard when returning the keyboard event, i.e. the keyboardHeight is as if the native soft keyboard is being shown (in IOS, only a small bar is displayed);

There's another plugin - cordova.externalkeyboard - for configuring external keyboard shortcuts, but it involves fiddling with xcode/swift native code, something I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your only goal for shrinkView to behave properly when using external keyboards? If so, you could try using the [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard). Like ionic's plugin, it's a fork of Apache's original keyboard plugin and fixes some issues including sizing with external keyboards.

Comment: Hi Connor, thank you for taking your time answering this question. I'll give it a try :) It's not on the PhoneGap Plugins Repository, so for those interested, using github repo as in 'phonegap plugin add https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard.git'